# Last Row VBA Error - Returning value as 1?

Tags: excel, vba

Hi All i have the below code within a macro but for some reason it keeps returning the last row as 1 even though it isnt the last row, any thoughts?

```
lr1 = Sheets("SAPExport").Cells(Rows.Count, "AZ").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("SAPExport").Range("AZ1:BB" & lr1).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=cell.Value
Sheets("SAPExport").Range("AZ1:BB" & lr1).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=("Y")

lr = Sheets("SAPExport").Cells(Rows.Count, "AZ").End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: How many rows are actually showing once the filter is applied?  If no rows are showing (apart from the headers) then 1 would be correct.

Comment: Hi kevin it loops through filters so sometimes 0 is correct but on others theres a couple of hundred but still only pulls 1 for some reason

Comment: I guess I should have qualified my question - are there values in column AZ in the filtered sheet?  Your test should find the last row with values in it in column AZ.

Comment: Could you post the complete code form `Sub` to `End Sub`. It's kind of hard to understand what you're trying to do e.g. if `lr1` is the last row, what does `lr` represent? At first glance it looks like a case for `SpecialCells` and/or `CurrentRegion`. Hard to know without the rest of the code and some clarifications. BTW `End`, and even `Find` 'don't like' `AutoFilter`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the "AZ" range. I guess the goal is to have the latest row of multiple columns ?

If so, try :

```
lr = Sheets("SAPExport").Columns("A:Z").Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
```

Comment: "AZ" is one single column like `A`, `B` etc. and not the same as `A:Z` which is a range of column `A` to column `Z`. Column names are `A`, `B`, `C`, …, `Y`, `Z`, `AA`, `AB`, …, `AZ`, …

Comment: `Columns("AZ:BB")` is a valid three-column range containing columns `AZ`, `BA`, and `BB`. It could also be written as `Range(Columns(52), Columns(54))` or `Columns(52).Resize(, 3)`... The lesson to be learned is that you can successfully use the `Find` method to calculate the row of the last record in a filtered range, if the filter doesn't include blanks. If it does, then only if the blank cells contain formulas evaluating to "", it can be done by using the `LookIn` argument set to `xlFormulas`. In this case the `Lookin` argument is not needed.

Comment: @VBasic2008 *"In this case the Lookin argument is not needed."* The `LookIn` argument is **always** needed! Check the documentation of the [Range.Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find#remarks) where it says *"The settings for LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, and MatchByte are saved each time you use this method. If you do not specify values for these arguments the next time you call the method, the saved values are used."* If you don't specify it, it will use whatever was used before in VBA or GUI. So it will be kinda random wether it works or not.

Comment: @ Pᴇʜ: And how could the result be different in this (OP's) case? The `"Y"` is ensuring the right result even if `Cell.Value = ""`. BTW I've never omitted the `LookIn` argument before, unless `Find` was called consecutively in a procedure. So it's kind of a shock for me, too. Of course, if the headers contain formulas evaluating to "", then you are right.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Ah, well the `"Y"` makes the difference ^^ you are right, missed that. Nevertheless I would recommend always to set these 4 mentioned arguments, just to make sure Excel does excactly the same everytime. Actually that these values are saved and have no defaults is a huge possible source for errors.